# Global object is not available in custom modules even when passed in and requested

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

**route1.js** code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var module1 = require('../modules/module1.js'); // custom module

    var globals = {
        a : 'A',
        b : 'B',
        c : 'C'
    };

router.post('/data', function(req, res){
  var data = req.body.form_input;
  // here we update the globals object with the data, mutate it or something
});

module.exports = {
    router : router,
    globals : globals
};
```

**module1.js** code:

```
var route1 = require ('../routes/route1.js');

console.log(route1.globals); // not working!?
```

Why is global not available in module1 even when I export it in route1 by module.export ?

EDIT:

Circular dependency happened when I require:
var module1 = require('../modules/module1.js');
and then in module1 i required:
var route1 = require ('../routes/route1.js');

so it jumps from model1 to route1, then again to model1 and to route1 and so on. By adding additional module - globals.js and adding it to module1 and route1 problem is solved - thanks to @Rashomon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a circular dependency here. Circular dependencies are difficult to manage and most of times its a sign of not well designed architecture.
I suggest you moving `globals` to a single file called `globals.js`.

Here you have a minimal example of a circular dependency problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-hill-94gdg?fontsize=14

Comment: You can move globals to a single file. Then both `route1` and `module1` can import them and modify them succesfully. But `route1` and `module1` cannot import themselves like you did in the first attempt.